# Applescript Error -4960 after MAC OS Update

Tags: applescript

I keep getting an error when I try to run this as part of a much bigger script. Doesn't like "to the folders". Only thing that changed on my end was an update to the MAC OS operating system (currently on Big Sur 11.6.5).

```
tell application "Finder" to set myFolders to the folders of theDestinationFolder

set folderCount to count myFolders
set loggingCounter to 0

repeat with aFolder in myFolders
    set progress description to "Processing folder " & (loggingCounter + 1) & " of " & folderCount
    set progress additional description to ""
    set progress total steps to folderCount
    set progress completed steps to loggingCounter
    
    organizeSubfolder(aFolder)
    
    set loggingCounter to loggingCounter + 1
    
end repeat
```

Comment: Your sample script works for me with Big Sur and a valid folder alias - can you edit your post to include a minimal example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Thanks for testing this @red_menace! You're comment gave my an idea. Right now theDestinationFolder in on a server and now I realize that's the problem. Everything runs fine if I do it locally.